# Setting numeric flags to strings in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas and was wondering what is the best way to deal with string data? I was thinking of numbering the strings with a flag but I am sure there is a better way to do this? The string values are to be incorporated in KNN as a feature.

Suppose the following data and suppose I numbered my type:

[image]

Just an example:
This will will obviously give me an `could not convert string to float`

```
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=15)
knn.fit(df['Type'], df['Quantity'])
```

Is there a way to do this without making "type" into numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scikit-learn as you have noticed does not accept string values as features. You must convert each string value to some numeric. You can add a flag column as you have done and as @piRSquared has shown with a pandas shortcut (also done with LabelEncoder in scikit-learn) but this encodes the values of your food type with a particular numerical ordering that may or may not make sense. Is Meat really twice as much as Fruit and is Bean 50% more than meat.

I would personally use `pd.get_dummies(df['Type'])` to make a new feature for every value of fruit.

Comment: I really thought there would be a better way, guess not. Thanks for the explanation and other suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

use the pandas function `factorize`

```
df.Type.factorize()
```

***demonstration***

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        [10000, 'Fruit'],
        [500, 'Fruit'],
        [100, 'Meat'],
        [400, 'Fruit'],
        [900, 'Meat'],
        [5830, 'Meat'],
        [2904, 'Bean']
    ], columns=['Quantity', 'Type'])

df['Flag'] = df.Type.factorize()[0]
df
```

[image]